# When a make a call to a public API, how does chainlink verifies the response or it does not?

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

Example -->
I made a API call to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 and got my desired response.
But how does chainlink verifies the information that it is indeed correct.
If not, is it not essentially removing one of the main benefits blockchain has **'decentrialization'**?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** The basic example from the [docs](https://docs.chain.link) is nothing but a building block of how to do it. It's an example of pulling from a single API through a single node. To make this decentralized, you'd have to pull many APIs through many different nodes.

The Chainlink Any API call feature should be considered the bare bones of a Chainlink node. One piece of the whole picture. Analogously, a single Ethereum node processing transactions would be centralized, and a single Chainlink node responding with API data would be as well.

So we need many Ethereum nodes to process transactions to verify the transactions are being processed correctly and many Chainlink nodes to verify the data are being processed correctly. So if you want to get data through Chainlink, you should use many nodes, and ideally many different data sources as well - and that's how you can verify the data is correct.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer @Andrej. But do you know how to do it?
And what if there is only one data source out there?